# C# method out value(s)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am new C# and and currently reading Murach's C# 2012. I came across methods that assign value to the arguments defined as out which I am a bit confused about. In other languages, if a method needs to return more than one value then an object can be returned which would include more than one value. However I am uncertain how to employ "out" within a method. I have also been following MSDN online resources but still not clear on how to use "out". For example, if I want to write a method which takes four arguments, how can I have this method to assign value to the arguments defined as "out".

```
private void calcValues(decimal decVal, out decimal decHigh, out decimal decMid, out decimal decLow)
{
    decimal highVal = 0.00M;
    decimal midVal = 0.00M;
    decimal lowVal = 0.00M;

    highVal = (decVal * decHigh);
    midVal = (decVal * decMid);
    lowVal = (decVal * decLow);

}//CALCVALUES METODH END
```

I would highly appreciate it if anyone can help me understand this "out" mechanism. I have done online search on this but was not able to come up with a plain vanilla example on it.

Thank you.

Comment: See whether http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html helps you - and don't be afraid to return a composite value instead. (I'm not a big fan of `out` parameters.)

Comment: @Jon is there any reason you dislike `out`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I believe in methods doing *one thing*. If a method needs to return more than one value, those values should be sufficiently related that it makes sense to encapsulate them in a type so that a single composite value can be returned.

Comment: I agree with Jon. I strongly discourage out parameters (and ref). YOu were surprised by their semantics, so other will be too plus you have to pre-create the result holder in the calling code. Return a compound type or a tuple if its a one-off. The only place where it kind of works is in the TryXXX methods that return a bool to indicate success

Comment: @JonSkeet - Would you have implemented the `.TryXXX` pattern in a different way if you had been in charge of the .NET framework?  Or, would this be an exception to your overall dislike of `out` parameters?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: See http://nodatime.org/userguide/text.html for my preferred approach to parsing :)

Comment: i see that nodatime uses out for its parsing routines - i was surprised given jon's comments about not liking them

Comment: @JonSkeet - Gotcha, so you'd have these implementations return a `ParseResult<T>` result that encapsulates both successes and failures, rather than use an `out` parameter.  I could probably get behind that design, though the pattern would be *messy* without the use of interfaces, which weren't available back in the 1.0 framework.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Interfaces were definitely in .NET 1.0. Do you mean generics? If so, I agree - but that doesn't mean it's a nice pattern *now*. (And for the sake of the relatively few `TryParse` calls, there could have been separate types...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry, brain fart; generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for all your help. I just didn't know how to use 'out' in method call for one or more than one value(s). Murach's 2012 C# is a good book but lacks minor details but that is just my opinion. So this is how I ended up using "out":

```
    decimal cdecLUX_RATE = 0.06M;               //LUXURY TAX RATE
    decimal cdecSTATE_RATE = 0.05M;             //STATE TAX RATE
    decimal cdecDEALER_FEES = 0.15M;            //DEALER FEES

    decimal decFullPrice = 30000.0M             //FULL PRICE
    decimal decLuxTax = 0.00M;                  //LUX TAX
    decimal decStateTax = 0.00M;                //STATE TAX 
    decimal decDealerFees = 0.00M;              //DEALER FEES  


    //CALCTAXES METHOD CALL
    calcTaxes(decFullPrice, out decLuxTax, out decStateTax, out decDealerFees);     

    private void calcTaxes(decFullPrice, out decimal decLuxTax, out decimal decStateTax, out decimal decDealerFees)
    {
        decLuxTax = (decFullPrice * cdecLUX_RATE);
        decStateTax = (decStatePrice * cdecSTATE_RATE);
        decdecDealerFees = (decFullPrice * cdecDEALER_FEES);
    }//CALCTAXES METODH END
```

This may not be the right way, but I am still getting my feet wet with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You just... *assign to them*:

```
decHigh = 0M;
decMid = 13M;
decLow = 42M;
```

Note that because they are `out`, you can't *read* from them until they are "definitely assigned"; their value upon entry is *not defined*. This is so that the caller can do this:

```
decimal foo;
if(SomeMethod("bar", out foo)) {...}
```

rather than having to assign an arbitrary value to `foo`:

```
decimal foo = 0M;
if(SomeMethod("bar", ref foo)) {...}
```

However, as you note: `out` is poorly understood. You might also consider simply returning something that *has* 3 values:

```
private SomeType CalculateValues(decimal decVal) {
    //... some maths...
    return new SomeType(...);
}
```

Comment: @zmbq:  Only if you want to consume it directly and only if the method keeps private. Tuples are not very readable.

Comment: @zmbq I disagree. What does `Item3` mean, exactly? I would prefer something with sensible names. If .NET allowed "internally visible structural anonymous types", that would be ideal.

Comment: I wouldn't use a tuple as part of an interface (as @Tim said), but for internal purposes it's very convenient. In fact, that's the whole point behind a tuple, why would you need it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really assigning anything to those out variables that is why they aren't being modified. After doing any calculation, simply assign the value you wish to store to those variables. Note, you do not have to re-declare them in the method.

Answer (score 0):

For example of how out parmeters are used, look at the TryParse methods for
built in types (e.g. int.TryParse, bool.TryParse).

Specifying a parameter as "out" allows the called procedure to assign a value
to the paramerter the value assigned to parameter will become the value of the
actual parameter (the variable passed in).   In fact the called procedure 
must assign a value.  For TryParse methods it will be the result of the parse, or the default
value or the default value for the type (e.g. 0 or false).  Whether this is implemented by
using indirection or by using a copy out mechanism, I don't know.  Might depend on whether it's a
a struct or class.

In C# both the caller and the called procedure must mark the parameter with the out parameter.
And obviously the actual parameter must be an lvalue (i.e. a variable or location that can be assigned to).

You might be confused because almost everything in C# is a reference, which means you can always change the public properties/fields of an object passed into a procedure.  The out mechanise allow you the change which object the actual parameter is referencing.

Comment: It was pointed out that this method currently isn't doing much. Well, what I would like to do is to pass in the parameters values and have the method "out" the values depending upon what is request such as "HighVal", "MidVal", or the "LowVal".